# How to break Vuex into modules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

am attempting to separate states, getters, actions and mutations into separate files within a particular module. well, i have tried but just cant figure out where the error below is coming from or how to fix it.

**ERROR**

[image]

**Here is the app structure**

[image]

**here is what i've done:**

in actions.js

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const actions  = {
    async getTodos(){
        let page_url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos';
        const res = await axios.get(page_url);
        console.log(res.data);
        this.commit('ALL_TODOS', res.data)
    }
}

export {
    actions
}
```

in getters.js

```js
const allTodos = (state) => state.todos

export default {
    allTodos
}
```

in mutations.js

```js
const ALL_TODOS = (state, payload) => state.todos = payload

export {
    ALL_TODOS
}
```

in state.js

```js
const state = {
    todos: []
}

export {
    state
}
```

my intention was to to import all these file into one index.js file within the todo folder `store/todo/index.js`.

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vue from 'vue';

import state from './state';
import getters from './getters';
import actions from './actions';
import mutations from './mutations';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store1 = new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    actions,
    getters,
    mutations,
  });
```

after i have done this, i want all the store i have created to available in `store/index.js` file like so

```js
import Todos from './modules/todo/index';

export default {
    Todos
}
```

This way, all i have to import in the `js/main.js` will be just `store/index.js` like i have done in the line below

```js
import store from './store/index';
```

Comment: I have a feeling the the problem has something to do with incorrect exports. Try removing the brackets around `actions` in `export { actions }` and replace it with `export default actions`. Also do this with `state` in state.js, and try adding a `default` after `export` in mutations.js. If you can create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) demonstrating this problem, it'll be much easier to help you

Comment: @marsnebulasoup exactly, i changed `export` to `export default {}` and it worked except that the promise returns `undefined`

Comment: You mean in `actions`? You aren't returning anything so it'll return undefined...

Comment: yeah, but `console.log(res.data)` was suppose to display the response i guess?

Comment: yeah, but `console.log(res.data)` was suppose to display the response i guess?

Comment: Oh that's right. So is *that* what's undefined? Or is the method not even being called. You can add something like `console.log('getting todos...')` to `getTodos()` so that you'll know if it is actually called or not.

Comment: i actually invoked the method in the computed as `this.getTodos()` the problem is with axios or fetch api, because i `console.log('Hello wolrld!')` and it worked

Comment: Okay so if you try logging axios to the console, can you see it? Perhaps you didn't install axios properly or something

Answer (score 0):

In vuex all actions take in parameter 'context' and call commit from it.
Please check documentation at https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Comment: @courage please reply to this answer.